# Question about applying Fubini when one of the variables appears in the integral boundary

Tags: real-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm writing a proof for the convolution theorem but I am stuck because I'm not so sure if I can apply Fubini's theorem in this case.

Here is what I've done so far ($\mathcal L$ is the Laplace transform):

$$ \begin{align}
\mathcal L (f) \cdot \mathcal L (g) (s) 
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f(x) dx \int_0^\infty e^{-sy} g(y) dy 
\end{align}$$

Now substitute $y=t-x$:

$$ \begin{align}
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f(x) dx \int_x^\infty e^{-s(t-x)} g(t-x) dt 
\end{align}$$

Now I would like to move $f(x)$ into the right integral and move $e^{-s(t-x)}$ into the left integral like this:

$$ \begin{align}
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} e^{-s(t-x)}  \int_x^\infty f(x) g(t-x) dx dt 
\end{align}$$

But because of the substitution the lower bound of the right integral depends on $x$ so I suspect I can't do this. Right? What can I do now?

Comment: What is $f$ and $g$, and what parameter values of $s$ do you have in mind?

Comment: @undefined Functions that satisfy the conditions so that their Laplace transform exists and $s$ is such that its real part is greater than the $\inf$ over all the $\alpha$ with $\mid f(t)\mid , \mid g(t) \mid \le K e^{\alpha t}$.